# Writing a test harness for a class

Tags: java

I have made a Selector concrete class with the code implementation placed inside it, the class extends from an abstract class and implements abstract methods.

```
public class Selector extends ASelector {

int max;
int min;


@Override
public void selectorRange(int min, int max) {

    this.min = min;
    this.max = max; 


}


@Override
public int selectorValue() {


      Random r = new Random();
      int randomNumber = r.nextInt(this.max - this.min) + min;
      return randomNumber;
    }

}
```

I have been asked to write a test harness to ensure the class is working. There is a template laid out like so:

```
public void run() {
    StdOut.println("DSA Coursework started\n");
    doPart1();
    doPart2();
    doPart3();
    doPart4();
    doPart5();
    StdOut.println("\nDSA Coursework completed");
}

private void doPart1() {

    StdOut.println("Part1 started\n");

 // Write test harness here   

    StdOut.println("\nPart1 completed");
    StdOut.println("==============================================\n");
}
```

I'm unsure as to how I would go about testing the class. What code do I need to write?

Comment: [Search for junit](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=junit&ia=about).

Comment: If you aren't going to use a test framework like `junit`, you can test manually by setting expectations and verifying them against an actual result for each test case.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you are supposed to test that the only method your class has returns the expected result? So you could start by doing something like this:

```
// Write test harness here
int min = 1;
int max = 10;
Selector selector = new Selector(min, max);
assert selector.selectorValue() >= min && selector.selectorValue() < max
```